# How to link Behat and Mink in Docker to Selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I have been running Behat, Mink and Selenium standalone server (with chrome) with no problems.

I'm now trying to run everything with Docker.  I have a container for the selenium hub plus chrome node, which I run with these commands:

```
docker run -d -p 4545:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug
```

I can browse to http://172.17.0.2:4444/grid/console and it seems as if the chrome node is running ok.

This is my behat.yml file

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            browser_name: chrome
            selenium2:
                wd_host: http://172.17.0.2:4444/wd/hub
                capabilities: { "browser": "chrome", "version": "71"}
            base_url: http://localhost:8080
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    log_file: 'mono.log'
                    admin_username: 'admin'
```

When I start my behat container, my feature files start to run as expected but they all fail.  It looks as if the behat container cannot find Selenium.

What config should I use so that my behat container can find selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is quite old, i think this might help others:

You have to specify the session for your suite like:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      mink_session: chrome

  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      default_session: chrome
      javascript_session: chrome
      sessions:
        chrome:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: localhost:4444/wd/hub
            capabilities: {"browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome"}
```